# 100% width footer not covering the whole page and isn't centred. How can I fix this?

Tags: css

```css
footer {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  clear: both;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

The footer isn't centred and all solutions I can find say that `width: 100%` should fix it, but it doesn't.

I've tried a lot of solutions from past questions about ill-centred footers here.

Comment: For testing purposes, if you change the footer's background color in the snippet to something darker, you will see the footer does go all the way across and the text is also centered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
footer {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  clear: both;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

try with max-width: 100%;
may be some css property applied fir max-width

Answer (score -1):

100% is 100% of the parent component, therefore not always 100% of the view.
You can use `width: 100vw` to make the component width 100% of the width of the page.